# How do I fix module 'petspgm' has no attribute 'PetData' error?

Tags: python, ide, attributeerror

I keep getting this error no matter what I do.  Its suppose to make a new data but it does not seem to want to work.  The full error is:

> line 35, in make_list
> pet = petspgm.PetData(pet_name, pet_type, pet_age)
> builtins.AttributeError: module 'petspgm' has no attribute 'PetData'

Here's the code for petspgm

```
class PetData:
    # The __init__ method initializes the attributes
def __init__(self, pet_name, pet_type, pet_age):
    self.__pet_name = pet_name
    self.__pet_type = pet_type
    self.__pet_age = pet_age

# This method accepts an argument for the pet's name
def set_pet_name(self, pet_name):
    self.__pet_name = pet_name

# This method accepts an argument for the pet's type
def set_pet_type(self, pet_type):
    self.__pet_type - pet_type

# This method accepts an argument for pet's age
def set_pet_age(self, pet_age):
    self.__pet_age = pet_age

# This method returns the pet's name
def get_pet_name(self):
    return self.__pet_name

# This method returns the pet's type
def get_pet_type(self):
    return self.__pet_type

# This method returns the pet's age
def get_pet_age(self):
    return self.__pet_age
```

and the code for the other one

```
import petspgm

def main():
    # Get a list of pet objects
    pets = make_list()
    
    # Display the data in the list
    print ('Here is the data you entered: ')
    display_list(pets)
    
# This function gets data deom rhe user for 3 pets. It returns a list of pet objects containing the data
def make_list():
    # Create an empty list
    pet_list = []
    
    # Add 3 pet objects to the list
    print ('Enter the data for 3 pets')
    for count in range(1, 4):
        # Get the pet data
        print ('Pet number ' + str(count) + ':')
        pet_name = input("Enter your pet's name: ")
        pet_type = input('Enter the type of pet: ')
        pet_age = input("Enter your pet's age: ")
        print
        
        # Create a new Pet Data object in memory and assign it to the pet variable
        pet = petspgm.PetData(pet_name, pet_type, pet_age)
        
        # Add the object to the list
        pet_list.append(pet)
        
    # Return the list
    return pet_list

# This function accepts a list containing Pet Data objects as an argument and displays the data stored in each object
def display_list(pet_lists):
    for item in pet_list:
        print ("Pet's name is: " + item.get_pet_name())
        print ("Pet's type is: " + item.get_pet_type())
        print ("Pet's age is: " + item.get_pet_age())

# Call the main function
main()

input('Press Enter to continue')
```

I have tried adding a pet data code but then the entire code crashes and the file wont be able to be opened by python.  I have tried using different wording in the coding and it give the same error. I've also just tried to make the list myself but it just crashes python.

Comment: I don't see how this code could produce that error.  Could you be mistaken about the contents of `petspgm.py`?  Perhaps there are two different files of that name in two different directories, and you're looking at the wrong one?

Comment: As a first debugging step, in the second module, show us the output of `dir(petspgm)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon There is only one file called petspgm as no other files showed up when I checked.